# Declaring a Test Dependency in Play!

Tags: java, playframework, dependency-management

Is there a way to declare a test dependency in the dependencies.yml file for the Play! Framework?  I don't see any information about test dependencies in the [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/dependency).

For example, I may want to use a testing library such as Mockito but not have its classes used in production for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that you can define dependencies per Play [framework ID](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/ids#id), similar to how you can define settings for a specific ID in the application.conf file. To do this, you need to add an additional `id` attribute to your dependency definition.

For example, if you wanted to only include mockito-core in environments with a framework ID of `test`, your dependencies.yml file would look like the following:

```
require:
    - org.mockito -> mockito-core 1.8.5:
        id: test
```

You can get this to work when using a single machine as well, although you have to be a bit more deliberate about it. To test with your test-only dependencies, you'd define your dependency with `id: test` and then run:

```
play dependencies --%test --sync
play test
```

Then, to switch back to production, you'd run:

```
play dependencies --sync
play run
```

The downside is that you have to remember to sync your dependencies every time you switch between test and production modes, but I think that this is currently the best you can do if you want to make sure that the dependency is only on the classpath when in test mode.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little confused.  Just to clarify, how would I then declare a mockito dependency that is required for test but isn't used when I do a "play run"? (and the ID is not test)

Comment: @digiarnie Well, if you have separate test and production environments, the one without the specified ID will not load that specific dependency when you call `play dependencies`. If both environments are the same (e.g. you're calling `play test` versus `play run`), it should still be manageable, you'll just have to sync the dependencies in between. I'll update the answer when I determine what the best way to do that is.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're doing there now.  I was confused before as I thought the "- dependency" you had was a keyword, but you actually meant the actual library (my bad).  Your suggestion looks to work but it's a little annoying to have to switch ids but it appears to be the only way right now.  Thanks for your insights.

Comment: @digiarnie Ah, sorry about that. I've updated the answer to use an actual dependency definition to avoid confusing anyone else.